# Accessing data member across Android application and activity

Tags: android-activity, android

We're working on a fairly complicated set of software for Android.  In order to simplify things (like common tasks), I'm in the process of moving some of the things our software does (like database access) into the Application so that the various activities can access them when necessary.

In an activity, I can use `getApplication()` `to` gain access to the Application's data members, but I can't figure out how to do the reverse from the Application.  Is there an easy way to gain "visibility" from an Android Application into its dependent Activities?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  What do you mean by "visibility from an Application *into* its activities?

Comment: I want the Application to have read access (at least) to at least some Activity data.  Android Activities have the getApplication() method, but I'm trying to accomplish the reverse procedure.

Comment: **I want the Application to have read access (at least) to at least some Activity data.** - Don't attempt to go down this road. Nothing outside of an `Activity` should have access to any of its internals directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Application` class (in general) should not be concerned with any `Activity` or other components.

Simply create a database helper (extend `SQLiteOpenHelper` for example) and have your `Application` create and hold a static reference to it.

```
public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    ...
}
```

For the `Application`...

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    protected static MyDBHelper dbHelper = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        dbHelper = new MyDbHelper();
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in any app component...

```
MyApp.dbHelper.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

What we've done is to create a `BaseActivity` class. All of our Activities inherit from the `BaseActivity` class. We've overridden most of the lifecycle methods in the `BaseActivity` so that we can keep track of the activity stack ourselves. In this way you can determine which activity is the "current" activity. To get information from the activity you can provide access methods in the `BaseActivity` that are overriden in the inherited activties.

I'm sure there are also other ways.

The biggest problem with this kind of architecture is that there is no really reliable way to determine which activity is the current running activity (ie: the activity at the top of the activity stack). There are a few hacky methods that rely on having permission to access all tasks but this really is not good.

Android needs to provide a way for an application to determine which activities are in the stack and in which order, but it doesn't.

When you do this, be aware that Android can (and will) **kill your process** whenever it wants to (if it is in the background) and that when the user returns to the application it will recreate the process (and your Application instance) and then it will recreate ONLY the activity that was on top of the task stack. It does **not** recreate all the activities that are underneath the top one **unless (and until)** the user returns to them.